# Salesforce community builder and Visualforce

Tags: salesforce, visualforce

I am looking at Salesforce Community builder and wanted to know if it is possible to add a visual-force page into the community builder page, for example with the lightning app builder - you could also add visual-force pages I was wondering if this is possible with the community builder pages or if it will be in the future. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

One way you could try is:

```
<iframe src="salesforce/apex/myvisualforcepage" />
```

Although it isn't perfect, and probably isn't supported, this seems to be the quickest way.

I haven't tested this in Winter '16, but it worked for me last time I needed.